# Rails/Prawn: how do I use rails helpers inside a Prawn class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, prawn

I'm trying to use `rails 3.2` helpers inside a `prawn` class, but rails throws:

```
undefined method `number_with_precision' for #<QuotePdf:0x83d4188>
```

**Prawn Class**

```
class QuotePdf < Prawn::Document
  def initialize(quote)
    super()

    text "sum: #{number_with_precision(quote.sum)}"
  end
end
```

**Controller**

```
def show
  @quote = current_user.company.quotes.where(:id => params[:id]).first
  head :unauthorized and return unless @quote

  respond_with @quote, :layout => !params[:_pjax] do |format|
    format.pdf do
      send_data QuotePdf.new(@quote).render, filename: "Devis-#{@quote.date_emission.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")}.pdf",
      type: "application/pdf"
    end
  end
end
```

**Thanks for your help.**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to explicitly include `ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper` (or any other helper class/module) in your prawn document class.

```
class QuotePdf < Prawn::Document
  include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper # <-

  def initialize(quote)
    super()

    text "sum: #{number_with_precision(quote.sum)}"
  end
end
```

Comment: Worked well for me in Rails 3.2.11.  Siekfried's did not.  Thanks!

Comment: include has to be outside of class (before definition of class) on latest rails version !!

Answer (score 9):

Just pass the `view_context` to the Prawn sub-class initializer.

```
def initialize(quote, view_context)
  super()
  @view = view_context
end
```

in Controller, change to:

```
QuotePdf.new(@quote, view_context)
```

then in Prawn sub-class, this will work:

```
@view.number_with_precision(quote.sum)
```

Comment: I like this method much better, as it keeps the @view and its methods distinct. This way you won't ever have something from ActionView accidentally monkeypatch something in Prawn::Document.

Answer (score 7):

If iafonov solution doesn't work, you may just have to include `NumberHelper` without the prefix.